# Paperclip with ActionCable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, websocket, paperclip, actioncable

Is there any way to pass a file through ActionCable? I'm trying to use Paperclip for the upload.

```
  <div id="messaging-form" class="form-group">
    <%= f.file_field :msg_image, id:"msg_image" %>
  <%= f.submit "Send", id: "data-send" %>
```

My Javascript is

```
return $('#new_message').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this
    $this = $(this);
    msg_image = $this.find('#msg_image');
    App.global_chat.send_message(msg_image.val());
    msg_image.val('');
    return false;
  }
});

//inside my App.cable.subscriptions.create
    send_message: function(msg_image) {
      return this.perform('send_message', {
        msg_image: msg_image
      });
    }


//message_broadcast_job.rb
class MessageBroadcastJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(data)
    message = Message.create!(msg_image: data['msg_image'])
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "conversations_#{message.conversation.id}_channel",
      message: message
  end

end
```

Clearly, just passing the image file path through msg_image.val() is not the proper way to do it. I need the actual data Paperclip needs to save the file properly.

The latest info I could find on this was from a year ago saying it was not possible to pass files through ActionCable. However, I was wondering if there was either any updates to that or if anyone has found a good hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since discovered that although Websockets can handle files, the Rails ActionCable cannot.